# Select only numeric fields including containing floats from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Raw dataframe (df):

```
     A    B
0    1    green
1    2    red
2    s    blue
3    4.3  yellow
4    b    black
```

Expected dataframe (df) after selecting:

```
     A    B
0    1    green
1    2    red
3    4.3  yellow
```

Trying:

Neither `df[df['A'].astype(str).str.isdigit()]` nor `df[df['A'].astype(str).str.isdemical()]` could get the expected result but as below:

```
   A      B
0  1  green
1  2    red
```

Hope:

- How to get what I want
- Explain why `isdigit()` and `isdemical()` fail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `pd.to_numeric(..., errors='coerce')`:

```
In [315]: df[pd.to_numeric(df.A, errors='coerce').notnull()]
Out[315]: 
     A       B
0    1   green
1    2     red
3  4.3  yellow
```

All non-integral values are converted to `NaN`. After that, use `df.notnull`, get a boolean mask and just index.

---

`isdigit()` and `isdecimal()` both fail because they look for whole numbers only. Floats are not recognised as being valid.

Comment: I was going to use the numeric and you just had to be quicker! +1

Answer (score 2):

Another simple method is to go in the opposite way i.e `isalpha != True`

```
df[df['A'].str.isalpha()!=True]
```

or

```
df[~df['A'].str.isalpha()]
```

or with `regex` using `str.match` i.e

```
df[df['A'].str.match(r'[+-]?([\d]*[.])?[\d]+')]
```

or

```
df[~df['A'].str.match(r'[A-z]')]
```

Output :

```
     A       B
0    1   green
1    2     red
3  4.3  yellow
```